# How to delete a favorite item from Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get the user to click on a heart icon they clicked to add an item to a list of favorites so that they can delete said item. I am not sure how to go about this, other than add a setOnClickListener to the button but then I'm not sure how to manage to get the exact item in my list. Any advice on how to do this?

This is the Favorites activity:

```
package com.example.newsapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.newsapp.DB.FavoriteViewModel
import com.example.newsapp.databinding.ActivityFavlistBinding

class FavoritesActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mfavoriteViewModel: FavoriteViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityFavlistBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favlist)
        binding = ActivityFavlistBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //recyclerview
        val adapter = FavoritesAdapter()
        binding.rvFavList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvFavList.adapter = adapter

        //favoriteViewModel
        mfavoriteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FavoriteViewModel::class.java)
        mfavoriteViewModel.readAllData.observe(this, Observer { favorite ->
            adapter.setData(favorite)
        })

    }

}
```

This is the adapter for this activity, where I want to add the option of deleting the item.

```
package com.example.newsapp

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.newsapp.DB.FavoriteViewModel
import com.example.newsapp.DB.Favorites
import com.example.newsapp.databinding.FavItemBinding
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class FavoritesAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var favoriteList = emptyList<Favorites>()

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val binding = FavItemBinding.bind(itemView)

        val favTitle: TextView = binding.tvFavTitle
        val favItem: ImageButton = binding.btnFavItem

        fun bind(favorites: Favorites) {
            Picasso.get().load(favorites.image).into(binding.ivFavsImage)
            favTitle.text = favorites.title
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fav_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(favoriteList[position])
        holder.favItem.setOnClickListener {
            //here is where i want to delete the item if user clicks the heart
            deleteFavorite(favoriteList[position])
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return favoriteList.size
    }

    fun setData(favorite: List<Favorites>){
        this.favoriteList = favorite
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun deleteFavorite(favorite: Favorites){
        //delete this item

    }
}
```

This is the favorites Dao

```
@Dao
interface FavoritesDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addFavorite(favorite:Favorites)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM favorite_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readALlData(): LiveData<List<Favorites>>

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteFavorite(favorite: Favorites)

}
```

Favorites viewmodel:

```
package com.example.newsapp.DB

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class FavoriteViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Favorites>>
    private val repository: FavoritesRepository

    init {
        val favoriteDao = FavoriteDatabase.getDatabase(application).favoriteDao()
        repository = FavoritesRepository(favoriteDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun addFavorite(favorite:Favorites){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.addFavorite(favorite)
        }
    }

    fun deleteFavorite(favorite:Favorites){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.deleteFavorite(favorite)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `function` in your `Activity` class which deletes an item from `DB`, then update your `RecyclerView` `adapter` to accept this function as parameter, and when any item is clicked (fav), just invoke this function.

Activity

```
private val deleteHandler: (Favorites)-> Unit = { 
    mfavoriteViewModel.deleteFavorite(it)
}

// When you create Recycler Adapter, pass the deleteHandler
val adapter = FavoritesAdapter(deleteHandler)
```

Adapter

```
// Update Adapter signature to except deleteHandler
class FavoritesAdapter(val deleteHandler: (Favorites) -> Unit ): RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritesAdapter.ViewHolder>()

// When item is clicked
holder.favItem.setOnClickListener {
    deleteHandler(favoriteList[position])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

everything is correct what you have done, only thing u need to do is pass the favorite object which you want to delete to ur view model, btw its better if you delegate the onClick events to your fragments/activity.

Like this in your adapter do this first

```
  private var onItemClickListener:((List<Favorites>) -> Unit)? = null

  fun setOnItemClickListener(listener:(List<Favorites>) -> Unit){
    onItemClickListener = listener
  }
```

and in your Activity

```
   adapter.setOnItemClickListener { //this wil pass the item on click as 
   //"it" you can change the name 
        mfavoriteViewModel.delete(it)
    }
```

below is the way how i do it in my app, i have a swipe to delete function

Fragment

```
   //code block of when user swipe
   override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, 
        direction: Int) {
            val position = viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition
            val article = newsAdapter.differ.currentList[position]
            cryptoViewModel.deleteArticle(article) <--- //delete function in viewmodel
        }
```

ViewModel

```
   fun deleteArticle(article: Article) = viewModelScope.launch {
    defaultRepository.deleteArticle(article)
}
```

Repository

```
 suspend fun deleteArticle(article: Article) {
    newsDatabase.getNewsDataDao().deleteArticle(article)
}
```

Dao Interface

```
@Dao
interface NewsDataDao {

@Delete
suspend fun deleteArticle(article: Article)
}
```

my full code can be found here and you can use for your reference if needed
https://github.com/zaidzak9/CryptoCurrencyTracker